# Determinar tamanho especifico para console em C

Tags: c, ubuntu, console

É possível definir um tamanho específico para o console do codeblock (Em linguagem C) abrir quando eu executar o programa?

Eu preciso que ele abra em um tamanho determinado, pois não vou usar a tela toda.

Vi que tem um jeito de fazer na biblioteca `windows.h` mas eu queria para o ubuntu e não estou encontrando.

OBS: Codeblock é o editor que estou usando para programar em C no ubuntu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A linha de comando que o codeblocks usa para ativar o console pode ser alterada em settings -> Environment -> General Settings.

No linux a default é:

```
xterm -T $TITLE -e
```

Você pode mudar a linha de comando do xterm alterando o tamanho da janela. Dê uma olhada no parâmetro -geometry na documentação do xterm.

Comment: Obrigada, vou ler a documentação e ver se é isso mesmo que preciso. ;)

Answer (score 2):

O comando `gnome-terminal --geometry=20x20 -e ./meuprograma` abre uma janela do terminal do Gnome de tamanho 20x20 (medido em caracteres) já rodando o programa `meuprograma` localizado no diretório atual.

Você pode fazer um arquivo de script que roda esse comando (ou seja, um arquivo .sh com esse comando dentro e marcado como executável) e distribuí-lo na mesma pasta que o binário. Isso vai dar o efeito que você deseja. Quanto ao Code::blocks, não sei dizer o que ele faz ou como faz, mas isso é irrelevante porque ele é apenas a IDE e não tem relação com o programa final.

Comment: No problema em questão a IDE tem relação já que o console é aberto por ela para executar o debugger; eu já cheguei a usar o gnome-terminal com o codeblocks mas, por algum motivo estranho, o funcionamento ficou errático o que acaba gerando dores de cabeça ao debuggar. Com o xterm, apesar do gdb dar um erro de terminal no início funciona perfeito.

Comment: Eu presumi que o AP não queria uma aplicação para ser rodada dentro de uma IDE todas as vezes pois não vejo sentido nisso.

Comment: Obrigada, vou ler sobre isso e tentar entender melhor como funciona. ;)